# RESTful client in order to test my POST method

Tags: java, rest, web-applications

I am working on the RESTful cloud application in java and once I implemented all the methods for POST, DELETE, PUT and GET, i need to test them through a simple java client. I successfully tested the GET and DELETE in the following manner:

```
String findById = target.path("..").path("..").path("17").request()
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class).toString();
System.out.println(findById);
```

But now when I want to try the PUT and POST, I can not make it work. I tried the following:

```
String addBook = target.path("..").path("..").queryParam("author", "OO")
                .queryParam("language", "OO")
                .queryParam("publisher", "OO")
                .queryParam("subject", "OO")
                .queryParam("title", "OO")
                .queryParam("isbn", "OO").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(String.class);
```

The error says that .post is expecting "The method post(Entity, Class) in the type SyncInvoker is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class)".

So my question is what the Entity should be and how should I specify it? Client project is running separately and not on the main(server) project.

Comment: I haven't worked with this, but looking at the code that works, it has .toString() after get, hmm, can you stick .toString() after post?

Comment: What tools are you using to write your application? Many frameworks have specific testing tooling (e.g., Spring MockMvc and even Spring REST Docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use query param to send a post request. 
You have to use a post body, that can be in different content types, like JSON.
You have to change your code to something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
body.put("language", "OO");
.....
String json = (new ObjectMapper()).writeValueAsString(body);
Entity<String> entity = javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.json(json);
String result = client.target(fullUrl).request().method("POST", entity, String.class);
```

Comment: @MarkoOtasevic Entity is javax.ws.rs.client.Entity ? and for Object Mapper you need Jackson core dependency. If you use Maven add this dependency to pom   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version> 
Instead if you use simple java add following to classpath
jackson-core-2.1.X,
jackson-databind-2.1.X

Comment: Thank you Nicolo, this is a great solution and works :)